# WPF BorderThickness disable child element padding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, border

I want to animate my button's BorderThickness property to 5 on MouseOver, everything works great except that when BorderThickness increases the content inside the button gets padded, which is something I don't want to happen. Is there a way to bypass/disable this?

Here is my code

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOverAnimation">
            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" To="3" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOutAnimation">
            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
        </Storyboard>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>


  <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
      <VirtualizingStackPanel   VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
          <ContentPresenter  Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>
      </VirtualizingStackPanel>
  </Border>

  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
          <Trigger.EnterActions>
              <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOverAnimation}"></BeginStoryboard>
          </Trigger.EnterActions>
      </Trigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

And here is the button in XAML

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource SoulsButton}" Width="150" >
    <TextBlock FontFamily="Resources/Fonts/#Univers UltraCondensed" FontSize="20"  Foreground="{StaticResource DarkSoulsYellow}" Width="50" Height="20">INSTALL</TextBlock>
</Button>
```

Comment: Try this, get rid of the width=150 and put it in a container with width of 150 instead, then change the button to horizonatalalignment of strech.

Comment: Nope doesn't work, the whole button appears as a jello now

Comment: Make the container the button is contained in a Grid.

Comment: Then the button control is growing from inside out.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of that annoying as followinging XAML. The Text will not be padded when border thichness change:

```
<Button Width="150" >
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOverAnimation">
                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" To="3" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                </Storyboard>
                <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOutAnimation">
                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                </Storyboard>
            </ControlTemplate.Resources>

            <Grid>
                <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel   VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    </VirtualizingStackPanel>
                </Border>
                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOverAnimation}"></BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOutAnimation}"></BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Foreground="Green">INSTALL</TextBlock>
</Button>
```